# How to group keyframes for materials?

Tags: materials, keyframes, dopesheet, nla-editor, actions

I'm looking for a way to group, move and copy material keyframes. For this I use the Dope Sheet, Action Editor and NLA. Unfortunately, it doesn't show any material keyframes in the Action Editor. If I now, for example, use Push Down Action to get the action into the NLA, the keyframes in the dope sheet disappear. Can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I am not much of an animator, but... Isn't it the whole point of Non Linear Animation Editor - NLA to edit animation strips of actions instead of keyframes?.. I believe you can edit those action by entering edit mode with tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I found out, only transformation keyframes are shown in Action Editor. Probably because you can select different actions in the Action Editor and combine them in the NLA and this is perhaps not wanted with materials. And like Martynas Žiemys said, select the strip animation and click Tab to make the keyframes visible in the dope sheet.

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAo7HxxxA08)